# Prove that exactly one solution of ODE converge

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

$xy'-(2x^2+1)y=x^2$
How can I prove that there is only one solution that is finite when $x\rightarrow \infty$
and how can I find it.

Comment: This is a linear ODE. Find its general solution.

Comment: Write as
$$\left( \frac{y}{x}\right)' = 2y+1,$$
then make substitution $y(x)=xz(x)$.

Comment: Did you find the general solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution can be written as $$y(x)=(C+\int_{0}^x e^{-t^2}\,dt)\,x\,e^{x^2}$$

If $y(x)$ is finite when $x \rightarrow \infty$ then 
$$C=-\int_{0}^\infty e^{-t^2}\,dt.$$

Note:
$$
0<- y(x)=\int_x^\infty e^{-t^2+x^2} \, x \,dt \le  \int_x^\infty e^{-t^2+x^2} \, t \,dt =\frac{1}{2} \; \forall x>0.
$$